# Limit number of lines in .net textbox

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

I am using the winforms textbox with multiline option ON. I want to limit the number of lines that can be entered in it. User should not be able to enter lines more than that.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Ramesh, I have added a new solution to my answer which would prevent users from adding more lines when max lines are exceeded. No need to edit or truncate the existing text box value. Thats the one you need to use.

Comment: @Rashmi, but that doesn't handle lots of scenario. Like copy paste, text wrapping etc..

Comment: Yes. I realised that. I am looking into it.

Comment: I have changed my answer to handle both user typing and pasting.

Comment: @Rashmi, still this does't work properly this.textBox1.Undo() is undoing all(lots of) changes instead of last character

Comment: Have u implemented both KeyPress and TextChanged? It will work only if both are implemented as e.Handled is set true in keypress, which would prevent TextChanged from being called when user is typing something in the textbox and it > MAX_LINES. If it still doesnt work, you might have to do some tweaking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to check for

`txtbox.Lines.Length`

You need to handle this for 2 scenarios: 1. User is typing in the textbox 2. User has pasted text in the textbox

**User typing in textbox**

You need to handle the key press event of the text box to prevent user from entering more lines when max lines are exceeded.

```
private const int MAX_LINES = 10;

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.textBox1.Lines.Length >= MAX_LINES && e.KeyChar == '\r')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I have tested the above code. It works as desired.

**User pastes some text in the textbox**

To prevent the user from pasting more than the max lines, you can code the text changed event handler:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.textBox1.Lines.Length > MAX_LINES)
    {
        this.textBox1.Undo();
        this.textBox1.ClearUndo();
        MessageBox.Show("Only " + MAX_LINES + " lines are allowed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: A mind trained to solve complex problems is often stumped by simplicity at first!

Comment: User should not be able to enter lines more than that

Comment: OK...You may have legitimate reason for doing so. Please see my answer.

Comment: modified a bit for my needs and for syntax/format in VB and worked perfectly for me, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't work because when you type continuously, it will be treated as 1 line irrespective of the no of lines you see on the screen.

In order to resolve the same, you need to use the SendMessage API to count the no of lines you see on the screen. Here is the code.

```
Private Declare Function SendMessageINT Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
        (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
Private Const EM_GETLINECOUNT = &HBA

Private Sub txtText1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtText1.KeyPress

    Const MAX_LINES = 13
    Dim lngCount As Long

    lngCount = SendMessageINT(txtText1.Handle, EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0, 0)

    If lngCount = MAX_LINES And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> Keys.Back And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> Keys.Delete Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Along with this, you need to find out the cursor position in the text box, so that you can allow the user to type. In the previous code, once it reaches to 13 lines, user won't be able to type in any line. In order to overcome that, you have to find out, the cursor is in which line. Use the below code for that.

Declare this along with the API declaration

Private Const EM_LINEFROMCHAR = &HC9

Below code must be placed in MouseDown, MouseUp, KeyDown and KeyUp events of the textbox.

intLineNo = SendMessageINT(txtText1.Handle, EM_LINEFROMCHAR, -1, 0&) + 1

After finding out the LineNo, you can do the evaluation in the KeyPress event of the TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, there is also the MaxLength property to set the number of characters you can enter in the textbox (since a line may have a variable length).

Comment: MaxLength does not help in limiting the no of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Limit to MAX_LINES with truncation for copy/paste.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( textBox1.Lines.Length >= MAX_LINES && e.KeyValue == '\r' )
            e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if ( textBox1.Lines.Length > MAX_LINES )
        {
            string[] temp = new string[MAX_LINES];
            for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_LINES; i++ )
            {
                temp[i] = textBox1.Lines[i];
            }

            textBox1.Lines = temp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void txttrccertificateto_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (txttrccertificateto.Text.Length > MAX_Char)
  {
    txttrccertificateto.Text = txttrccertificateto.Text.Remove(MAX_Char, 1);
  }
  if (txttrccertificateto.Lines.Length > MAX_LINES)
  {
    string[] temp = new string[MAX_LINES];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LINES; i++)
    {
      temp[i] = txttrccertificateto.Lines[i];
    }

    txttrccertificateto.Lines = temp;
  }
}

private void txttrccertificateto_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (txttrccertificateto.Lines.Length >= MAX_LINES && e.KeyValue == '\r')
    e.Handled = true;
  if (txttrccertificateto.Text.Length >= MAX_Char && e.KeyValue == '\r')
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void txttrccertificateto_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (txttrccertificateto.Lines.Length >= MAX_LINES && e.KeyValue == '\r')
    e.Handled = true;
  if (txttrccertificateto.Text.Length >= MAX_Char && e.KeyValue == '\r')
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi @santosh, and welcome to stackoverflow. It would be nice if you explain what the code does and why.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but here's my solution.  You basically check if either the first or last character is out of the client area.  For some reason, if the first character gets scrolled out of the box, its Y value will be greater than 0 which is why I also check it.  This works for both line breaks, copy/paste and character wrapping.

```
Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.TextChanged
     If Not Me.Multiline OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Text) OrElse _InTextChanged Then Exit Sub
     _InTextChanged = True

     Try
        Dim posLast As Point = Me.GetPositionFromCharIndex(Me.Text.Length - 1)
        Dim posFirst As Point = Me.GetPositionFromCharIndex(0)

        Dim sizeLast As SizeF
        Dim sizeFirst As SizeF

        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Me.Handle)
           sizeLast = g.MeasureString(Me.Text(Me.Text.Length - 1).ToString(), Me.Font)
           sizeFirst = g.MeasureString(Me.Text(0).ToString(), Me.Font)
        End Using

        If posLast.Y + sizeLast.Height > Me.ClientSize.Height OrElse posFirst.Y < 0 OrElse posFirst.Y + sizeFirst.Height > Me.ClientSize.Height Then

           Me.Text = _PreviousText

           If _PreviousSelectionStart > Me.Text.Length Then
              Me.SelectionStart = Me.Text.Length
           Else
              Me.SelectionStart = _PreviousSelectionStart
           End If


        End If
     Catch ex As Exception

     End Try

     _InTextChanged = False


  End Sub

  Private Sub Textbox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
     _PreviousSelectionStart = Me.SelectionStart
     _PreviousText = Me.Text
  End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

OK. How about defining a instance variable "lastKnownGoodText" and doing something like this:

```
private void textBox_TextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (textBox.Lines.Length > 10)
        textBox.Text = lastKnownGoodText;
    else
        lastKnownGoodText = textBox.Text;
}
```

Comment: Its a good approach. Though I am not sure about lastKnownGoodText. It can be drastically different if the user does a copy-paste to enter the text and he might lose his newly copied text. Why not truncate instead?

Comment: Yes you are right. It should be truncated rather than being restored to last known good version.

Comment: I have edited my response which now does not need truncation at all.